# How to push UI component to Existing Screen from other function in react native

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, modal-dialog

I have created alert popup and want to push it to current screen as soon as I call function just like Alert.alert(title).

How can I achieve it in react native.

I want to know the method I can use here to achieve UI I describe

Comment: try with custom hooks

Comment: @zainalabidin but how can i do without putting any code in render return

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to use HOC https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

You can create HOC which adds a placeholder with your message container View and add some handler for a state change. If you don't use any state manager you can create a Context where you can store your information about the alert state and connect it to HOC.